# javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF](Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I trying to add JavaMail in my web application.

**My context:**

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mail/gmail.com.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">${mail.smtps.auth}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${mail.port}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
        <property name="protocol" value="${mail.protocol}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="from" value="${mail.from}" />
        <property name="subject" value="Mail subject" />
    </bean>
```

**My properties:**

```
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=465
mail.username=my@gmail.com
mail.password=my
mail.from=my@gmail.com
mail.protocol=smtps
mail.smtps.auth=true
```

**My Service:**

```
@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo(to);
        mailMessage.setText(body);
        try {
            mailSender.send(mailMessage);
        } catch (MailException mailException) {
            mailException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1363)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:836)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:375)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:25)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.addUser(Unknown Source)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.web.UserController.registrationUser(UserController.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***In the same time if I trying that:***

```
try (GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext()) {
            context.load("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
            context.refresh();
            JavaMailSender mailSender = context.getBean("mailSender", JavaMailSender.class);
            SimpleMailMessage templateMessage = context.getBean("templateMessage", SimpleMailMessage.class);
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage(templateMessage);
            mailMessage.setTo("art15@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.setText("Hello");
            try {
                mailSender.send(mailMessage);
                System.out.println("Mail sended");
            } catch (MailException mailException) {
                System.out.println("Mail send failed.");
                mailException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

***I don't have a problem:***

*Failed message 1:

javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]*

***Why I have problem in my first example? How fix this?***

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of your previous question.  If it is not, please explain what's different.

Comment: @BillShannon it's a same question. If you known answer, please explain how fix the problem

Comment: Bad, bad, bad.  DO NOT post duplicate questions.  It DOES NOT make people more likely to help you.  Go back to your original question, read my comments, and do what I said so that you can provide me enough information to help you.

Comment: @BillShannon I can't understand how fix this problem

Comment: I'm not answering anything here.  Go back to your original post.

Comment: @BillShannon, thank you so much. Problem sloved

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the below property

```
"mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"
```

Below is how it looks

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="587" />
        <property name="username" value="XX"/>
        <property name="password" value="XX"/>

        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help, get a same error

Comment: @studentST Try changing the port to 587 once. As you are using gmail smtp server.